# Xcode 4.5.1, Cordova 2.2, jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, xcode, cordova

I'm trying for the first time to get JQuery mobile (1.2.0) to work with Xcode with Phonegap (2.2.0). The Xcode/Phonegap installation works - it has been setup according to

https://web.archive.org/web/20200806105755/http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html

I've then added jquery mobile css and js to www/js ad www/css of this project, and got a simple index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css"/>

        <title>Test of jquery mobile</title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 

       <body>
            <div data-role="page" id="liveListPage">
                <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" >
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                </div>
                
                <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"  >
                    <h1>Footer</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
               
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

But when pushing Run - it builds fine, but the jquery mobile doesn't seem to go into action at all - I just get h1 'Header' and 'Footer' with no fixed position and no theme.
My Scheme is <My App>/iPhone 6.0 Simulator.

What am I doing wrong? There are no errors in the log window.

Comment: Is this HTML document in the `www` directory? Also, I'm pretty sure that the root of your site should be located at: `/assets/www/` (is it different for iOS than Android?).

Comment: @Jasper if I right it is in the same place well in the `www` folder well thats what the docs say anyway

Comment: also I notice your scripts are not in the `head` or `body` they really should be in the `head`

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure if this is the problem but I noticed that your scripts are not it **head** or in the **body** which they should be in either one so i always out them in the head. So this is what I would of done

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css"/>

            <title>Test of jquery mobile</title>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>               
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script> <!--your script-->


        </head>
           <body>
                <div data-role="page" id="liveListPage">
                    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" >
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"  >
                        <h1>Footer</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </body>
        </html>
```

**Edit::** I also noticed after someone pointed it out that your script file is above the jQuery files so it won't register the jQuery library so I would move your `index.js` file down a bit so its below the jquery library files

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes js should be in head - my mistake - but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities here:

- The build isn't actually up to date - xcode doesn't always detect changes to the web files, so when you run on the device you see an older version. A clean usually fixes this one.
- The link is slightly wrong - usually it's a casing issue, as unlike the desktop OS, iOS is case sensitive. If you attach the safari web inspector to your app, you can see which files didn't load.
- The link is completely wrong - does the html work when opened in a desktop browser?

Answer (score 0):

change the sequence of your script files. also i noticed that you are not loading the css file with jqm. hence you can try first by loading from the jquery website. The sequence in which you load the js and css files are very important.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you - very much - that was it - the sequence - nice

Comment: no problem. im glad it helped you out. please help to mark it as answered :)